# Rails json with keys that respond to method calls

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing an RSpec test for some code that uses the [Google API Client for Gmail](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client).

When I query an email, I get back a `Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message` object.

For testing, I created a fixture file called 'gmail_message_spec.json' that replicates the important methods of the object, but as JSON:

```json
{"id": "17d38b2e48f6fake",
 "payload":
  {"headers":
    [{"name": "MIME-Version", "value": "1.0"},
     {"name": "Date", "value": "Fri, 19 Nov 2021 09:56:27 -0500"},
     {"name": "Message-ID", "value": "<CAG4LXW=jEzKkfOLnE5jOSo7ertC=gAj-6GKE1qO=P8KB19fake@mail.gmail.com>"},
     {"name": "Subject", "value": "Make a simple message for testing"},
     {"name": "From", "value": "Test Person <Test@20liters.org>"},
     {"name": "To", "value": "Test Person <Test@person.me>"},
     {"name": "Content-Type", "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"000000000000cc6f1d05d1257a61\""}],
   "mime_type": "multipart/alternative",
   "parts":
    [{"mime_type": "text/plain", "body": {"data": "This is a very simple message.\r\n"}},
     {"mime_type": "text/html", "body": {"data": "<div dir=\"ltr\">This is a very simple message.</div>\r\n"}}]},
 "snippet": "This is a very simple message."}
```

So, in my spec, I can load in this fixture as a demo response:

`response = JSON.parse(File.read("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/gmail_message_spec.json"), symbolize_names: true)`

However, my code expects the response to be an object and tries to perform method calls:

`response.payload.headers`

Since the testing object is JSON, I'd need to access it like a hash:

`response[:payload][:headers]`

It seems my options are:

1. Manually re-create the `Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message` object
2. Write a bunch of stubs: `allow(response).to receive(:payload).and return(response[:payload])`
3. Get the JSON to respond to methods as an object does.

I'm aiming for option #3 first. The other two options seem a bit tedious, especially #2.

**Is there a way to get a `Hash` with deeply symbolized keys to allow for method calls that retrieve keys?**

Instead of having to write this: `response[:payload][:headers]`

I want to write this: `response.payload.headers`

Answer (score 1):

Of course I just [rubber ducked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) myself.

I can use OpenStruct: `JSON.parse(File.read(), object_class: OpenStruct)`

```rb
response = JSON.parse(File.read("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/gmail_message_spec.json"), object_class: OpenStruct)
```

Thanks to [Someth Victory](https://medium.com/@somethvictory/converting-json-to-an-object-in-ruby-e64e6acf8a3b) and their very good Medium article from 2018.